# Relationship using a self-join

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy

How can I declaratively define a relationship on a SQLAlchemy model that joins the right table in the following manner:

```
SELECT *
FROM left_table left
JOIN left_table inter ON left.inter_id = inter.id
JOIN right_table right ON right.id = inter.right_id;
```

The culprit here is that the left table and the junction table are the same.

The following code generates a query that is close, but SQLAlchemy generates the wrong primaryjoin condition `... on left_table_1.inter_id = left_table_1.id` instead of `... on left_table_1.inter_id = left_table.id`. I've tried using an alias table, but that didn't work.

```
class Left(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'left_table'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    inter_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('left_table.id'))
    ...
    right = db.relationship(Right, secondary="left_table", lazy="joined", uselist=False)
```

Comment: Please file a bug report at https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues